# Is there any way how to modify message by Google apps script before forwarding please?

Tags: google-apps-script

Action in Gmail:
Remove/hide sender's email address and modify string/word in email's body.

Comment: Please see [how-do-i-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
function doGet() {
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
var text = (message.getPlainBody()); // get contents of the body
message.reply(text) //return contents
}
```

Try looking at this for more options [(here)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail#gmailmessage)